# Update column with variable

Tags: mysql, c#

Employee table

| ID | EmployeeSRN | Name | SupervisorID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10101 | Akash | 2 |
| 2 | 10111 | Smeeta | 4 |
| 3 | 10201 | samir | 5 |

I want to update SupervisorID of Akash to Samir's ID, i.e. 3. In my C# function, the only parameter I receive is Akash's EmployeeSRN and Samir's EmployeeSRN.

How can I write a single update statement to update Akash's SupervisorID to 3, in mysql?

Comment: Why tag it with Workbench, when the client is C#?

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE Employee
    SET SupervisorID =
       ( SELECT ID
             FROM Employee
             WHERE EmployeeSRN = ?
       )
    WHERE EmployeeSRN = ? ;
```

(Someone else can advise on how to substitute values into the query for C# without risking sql-injection.)